# CSS Dynamic Positioning of Relative Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How would I dynamically change the size of an element with `position:relative;`? I tried using a `width:45%;` to make it so it was always 45% of it's container, but when changing the browser size, I found that it remained the size it initially loaded, when I refreshed the page, it was smaller, but stayed smaller when I made the page bigger.
I will accept jQuery and/or Javascript solutions, but would highly prefer CSS. Also, if this seems to be an error with my code, and not due to the way `position:relative;` works fundamentally, let me know and I'll add my code to the post in a fiddle.

**EDIT: Code Added**

```
<div id="container">
<p class="caption">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/NpEaa2P7qZI/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="Placeholder"> <span>
                <b>This is the Caption's Title</b>
                This is the caption's description
            </span>

</p>
```

View the rest [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hv1hvqhs/)

It seems to work in the fiddle, not sure why it won't work client side.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py I added my code.

Comment: Could not find any issue..

Comment: Your fiddle was broken. The javascript wasn't executing. I changed the `$(window).load(function()...` to just `$(function() ...` and it seems to work. [New Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hv1hvqhs/3/)

Comment: Ah there, now it's not resizing. So that just means it has something to do with the script. Also, if it helps, I'm using Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is because of the javascript that is getting executed on page load.

When it iterates over your `.captions` is sets an inline style to the `.caption` of a width and height.

This part:

```
...
     $(this)
        // Add the following CSS properties and values
        .css({
            // Height equal to the height of the image
            "height": $(this).children("img").height() + "px",
            // Width equal to the width of the image
            "width": $(this).children("img").width() + "px"
        })
...
```

jQuery `.css` sets inline styles, so when you resize your window nothing changes because the `img` has static width and height.

You are trying to override this in your CSS with the `!important` declaration but the inline styles are winning out.

Removing this block of code seems to fix the problem, but I don't know if it will introduce other problems.

I have also put this code in its own function called `setCaptionSize()` and fire it when the page loads and attach it to the window resize event.

```
$(function () {
   setCaptionSize();
   $(window).resize(setCaptionSize);    
});
```

I also moved the hover event out of `setCaptionSize` so it wouldn't get bound multiple times.

See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hv1hvqhs/5/) for a demo

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but I think I might use another way of doing it found here: http://jsfiddle.net/WEWvs/2/ much simpler and cleaner.